# axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin wsdl File in other Artifact

Tags: maven, apache-axis, wsdl2code

Given Dependency A with WSDL File a.wsdl under src/main/resources/wsdl I'd like to include it in Dependency B which has a compile dependency to A to generate the Axis Classes with

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generateServerSide>false</generateServerSide>
                        <packageName>com.foo</packageName>
                        <wsdlFile>/wsdl/a.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        <databindingName>adb</databindingName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

when the a.wsdl is stored in Artifact B it works fine but moving it to A does not work the java.io.FileNotFoundException points to the wsdl Folder in Artifact B.

Is there a possibility to include wsdl Files which are in another Artifact as the axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the WSDL file from artifact A during the build of artifact B:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <includes>**/*.wsdl</includes>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wsdl</outputDirectory>
                <includeArtifactIds><artifact-a></includeArtifactIds>
                <includeGroupIds><artifact-a-group-id></includeGroupIds>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>bar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generateServerSide>false</generateServerSide>
                <packageName>com.foo</packageName>
                <wsdlFile>${project.build.directory}/wsdl/extracted/path/to/a.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                <databindingName>adb</databindingName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: hi orien, that's also what i did. Apparently this leads to Errors when working with m2Eclipse Plugin ( jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-98 ) but i did not find a better solution